# How to add a custom linkbutton to devexpress gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress's GridView. I have edit button working fine. I need to add a new custom linkbutton, which when clicked should show DevExpress's modal popupwindow to gather few input values and execute a method in codebehind. Please let me know how to do it. Not sure why it is so hard to achieve such a simple requirement.I couldn't find any sample code even for adding a custom link button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you get started with the [E1120](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1120.aspx) example.

Comment: The link was really useful. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing as you mention GridView which is a Winforms grid but also mention CodeBehind which suggests Asp.Net

[To Add repository items to the Winforms grid](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3085)

If you are referring to the AspxGridView then you can use the standard Asp.Net Templating feature and add any control to a column.

Comment: It is an asp.net application.